# CF ORM Many-To-Many with StructKeyColumn same as PK for related object

Tags: orm, coldfusion

Background: I'm attempting to change a Transfer ORM based app to a Hibernate ORM app as transparently as possible.

I'm having problems with ManyToManys with a collection type of Struct, when the primary key of the related table is the struct key

Transfer would let you do this:

```
<manytomany name="Timezone" table="RegionTimezones" lazy="false">
    <link column="RegionID" to="regions.Region"/>
    <link column="TimezoneID" to="regions.Timezone"/>
    <collection type="struct">
        <key property="TimezoneID"/>
    </collection>
</manytomany>
```

The equivalent Hibernate/CFProperty tag is:

```
<cfproperty name="Timezones" fieldtype="many-to-many" linktable="RegionTimezones" cfc="Timezone" singularName="Timezone" FKColumn="TimezoneID" inversejoincolumn="RegionID" type="struct" structkeytype="string" structkeycolumn="TimezoneID" />
```

However this errors with
"Repeated column in mapping for collection: Region.Timezones column: TimezoneID"

It appears that structkeycolumn cannot be the PK of another table.

My problem is that I have lots of existing calling code that takes advantage of Transfer's way of doing things.

Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?  I have herd people talking of a One-To-Many with link table, but can't find any references of how to do this in CF?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I encountered the same limitation before, but didn't find a workaround so I ended up using array instead.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I have gone with your Array idea and added methods such as getXXXStruct() that loops through the array.